# What's the purpose of a POSIX timer with no signal handler?

Tags: c++, linux

```
void EventProviderLinux::waitForEvents (EventLoopTime wait_time)
{
    AIPSTACK_ASSERT(m_cur_epoll_event == m_num_epoll_events);

    namespace chrono = std::chrono;
    using Period = EventLoopTime::period;
    using Rep = EventLoopTime::rep;
    using SecType = decltype(itimerspec().it_value.tv_sec);
    using NsecType = decltype(itimerspec().it_value.tv_nsec);
    using NsecDuration = chrono::duration<NsecType, std::nano>;

    static_assert(Period::num == 1);
    static_assert(Period::den <= std::nano::den);
    static_assert(std::is_signed_v<Rep>);
    static_assert(std::is_signed_v<SecType>);
    static_assert(TypeMax<Rep> / Period::den <= TypeMax<SecType>);
    static_assert(TypeMin<Rep> / Period::den >= TypeMin<SecType> + 1);

    if (wait_time != m_timerfd_time || m_force_timerfd_update) {
        m_force_timerfd_update = true;

        EventLoopTime::duration time_dur = wait_time.time_since_epoch();

        SecType sec = time_dur.count() / Period::den;
        Rep subsec = time_dur.count() % Period::den;
        if (subsec < 0) {
            sec--;
            subsec += Period::den;
        }

        struct itimerspec itspec = {};
        itspec.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
        itspec.it_value.tv_nsec =
            chrono::duration_cast<NsecDuration>(EventLoopTime::duration(subsec)).count();

        // Prevent accidentally disarming the timerfd.
        if (itspec.it_value.tv_sec == 0 && itspec.it_value.tv_nsec == 0) {
            itspec.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;
        }

        if (::timerfd_settime(*m_timer_fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &itspec, nullptr) < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error(formatString(
                "EventProviderLinux: timerfd_settime failed, err=%d", errno));
        }

        m_timerfd_time = wait_time;
        m_force_timerfd_update = false;
    }

    int wait_res;
    while (true) {
        wait_res = ::epoll_wait(*m_epoll_fd, m_epoll_events, MaxEpollEvents, -1);
        if (AIPSTACK_LIKELY(wait_res >= 0)) {
            break;
        }

        int err = errno;
        if (err != EINTR) {
            throw std::runtime_error(formatString(
                "EventProviderLinux: epoll_wait failed, err=%d", err));
        }
    }

    AIPSTACK_ASSERT(wait_res <= MaxEpollEvents);

    m_cur_epoll_event = 0;
    m_num_epoll_events = wait_res;
}
```

This function is supposed to block until there are events on `m_epoll_fd`. You can see that there is a timer `m_timer_fd` that is created but never given a handler. What is the point of starting a timer with no handler?

Also, I don't see any usage of this timer anywhere else. Since its created locally, there's no usage in its class. It must have a local usage.

Function taken from [here](https://github.com/ambrop72/aipstack/blob/c84eadf4b5cb5d33af0bf116d17331b32986bc94/src/aipstack/event_loop/platform_specific/EventProviderLinux_impl.h#L118)

Comment: The timer is monitored by the `epoll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [timerfd_create man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) (emphasis mine):

> These system calls create and operate on a timer that delivers timer
>          expiration notifications via a file descriptor.  They provide an
>          alternative to the use of setitimer(2) or timer_create(2), with the
>          advantage that the file descriptor **may be monitored by select(2),
>          poll(2), and epoll(7)**.

From the original source code:

```
control_epoll(EPOLL_CTL_ADD, *m_timer_fd, EPOLLIN, &m_timer_fd);
```

From the above we can see that the timer events have been set up to be monitored via `epoll`.